# If $\tan\theta=a \tan\left(\frac{\theta}{3}\right)$ express $\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{3}\right)$ in terms of $a$

Tags: trigonometry

I have this question: If $\tan\theta=a \tan(\frac{\theta}{3})$ express $\tan(\frac{\theta}{3})$ in terms of $a$. Sure I can divide both sides by $a$, but I think the question is about expressing $\tan\theta$ into $a$ as well. I wouldn't mind getting some help here. Thanks

Comment: Sorry! My typo, I've edit.

Comment: the point is expressing $tan \theta/3$ in terms of $tan \theta$ emplying trigonometric formulas, then the result follows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this identity:

$$ \tan 3x = \frac{3\tan x - \tan^3 x}{1 - 3\tan^2 x}.$$

Usually we write that with $\theta$ instead of $x$ but in your case you
want to replace $x$ with $\frac\theta3$.

Further hint: It is always possible to satisfy
set $\tan\theta=a \tan\left(\frac\theta3\right)$ by setting 
$\tan\left(\frac\theta3\right) = 0$.
Depending on the value of $a$, there will be exactly two other possible
values of $\tan\left(\frac\theta3\right)$, because if $\tan\left(\frac\theta3\right)$
satisfies the equation then $\tan\left(-\frac\theta3\right)$
also satisfies the equation.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\theta/3=\phi$ and use:
$$
\tan 3\phi=\dfrac{3 \tan \phi -\tan^3 \phi}{1-3\tan^2 \phi}
$$
You find a $3$-degree equation that you can easely factorize and solve.